# Capture only UIView 2 finger UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a couple of `UIScrollView`s in my view controller. I want to overlay a view that captures a 2 finger swipe via `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which will not record the `UIScrollView` swipe gestures.

When I put a transparent view over my content with a 2 finger pan gesture, my taps and 1 finger swipes are not detected.  I tried overwriting the `pointInside:` method to return `NO`
but then it doesn't record my 2 finger swipe.

The effect is similar to the 4 finger swipe to change apps.

Comment: so want your scrollviews not to capture 2 finger swipes?

Comment: @AndyJacobs Do you want the scroll view to detect the pan or no? You want to add over lay which will detect 2 finger pan and scrollview to detect other pans right? If i am thinking it wrong please clarify it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need an overlay view.
First implement `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that will handle 2 finger pan and assign it to your view that contains `UIScrollView`s

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                initWithTarget:self 
                                                        action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

Use `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to handle 2 finger pan with `UIScrollView` pan gesture

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

And finally you are able to handle 2 fingers pan

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"pan");
}
```

If you want to stop scrolling `UIScrollView` when two finger pan is detected you can disable and enable `UIScrollView` pan recognizers

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        _scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        _scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"pan");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't really need the overlay you can solve this with just gesture recognizers.  I wrote this up as a test:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 2, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    UIView *green = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [green setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    UIView *blue = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0)];
    [blue setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    [_scrollView addSubview:green];
    [_scrollView addSubview:blue];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerPan:)];
    [pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [pan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [pan setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];

    [_scrollView addGestureRecognizer:pan];

    [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
}

- (void)twoFingerPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
            self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"2 Fingers!");
}
```

I get the `twoFingerPan:` call back for when 2 fingers are used. The scroll view's `panGestureRecognizer` is still working at that point so I disable scrolling on the scroll view to handle the 2 finger pan.  I've found this method work's pretty well. One sort of wonky thing is if the scroll view is decelerating the 2 finger gesture recognizer isn't called.  Hope that helps!