# How do own Gesture Recognizer Swipe

Tags: ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I've a question.. I would like to do my own gesture recognizer with swipe and that you drag (or swipe) down with two fingers but I don't now how..

This is my code of **GestureSwipe.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GestureSwipe : UIGestureRecognizer

@property CGPoint startTouchPosition;

@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger numberOfTouchesRequired;
@property(nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction;


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

This is my code of **GestureSwipe.m**:

```
#define VERT_SWIPE_DRAG_MAX  7

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    // startTouchPosition is a property
    self.startTouchPosition = [aTouch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [aTouch locationInView:self.view];
    //  Check if direction of touch is horizontal and long enough
    if (fabsf(self.startTouchPosition.y - currentTouchPosition.y) <=
        VERT_SWIPE_DRAG_MAX)
    {
        // If touch appears to be a swipe
        if (self.startTouchPosition.y < currentTouchPosition.y) {

            [self myProcessDownSwipe:touches withEvent:event];
        }
        self.startTouchPosition = CGPointZero;
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        self.startTouchPosition = CGPointZero;
}

-(void)myProcessDownSwipe:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

How should I do to do swipe down with two fingers?

Then I have other VC where recognize my own gesture:

**HelloViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //newGesture = [[GestureSwipe alloc] init];

    newGesture = [[GestureSwipe alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showImage:)];

    newGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;


}
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the UISwipeGestureRecognizer documentation, you can set the number of touches required (so, 2 in this case) and the direction (down) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I saw that and I use that properties but I don't know where I need to use that properties: `@property(nonatomic) NSUInteger numberOfTouchesRequired;
@property(nonatomic) UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction;`

Comment: You would use it on the swipe gesture recogniser itself, I'll add more detail in an answer so I can include formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

In HelloViewController you'd add something like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

// Set the acceptable swipe direction and number of touches required to do the gesture
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

// Add the gesture recogizer to the view
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Then you would create a custom method (I called my one handleSwipe:, but this can be whatever suits you best) and do what you need to do.

EDIT: So your viewDidLoad method would look like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];

   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

   recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Set the acceptable swipe direction and number of touches required to do the gesture
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
    recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

    // Add the gesture recogizer to the view
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


}
```

And the handleSwipe: method could be like this:

```
-(void)handleSwipe:(id)sender{

    // Do something

 }
```

Comment: Why? I need to do a own Gesture Recognizer from my Class GestureSwipe.h no UISWipeGestureRecognizer

Comment: What does your own class do that differs from the standard swipe gesture recogniser? There's no point in reinventing the wheel, and even if you need your own class you should really have it be a subclass of UISwipeGestureRecognizer, unless I've misunderstood the purpose of your class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create your own recognizer. You can handle this with a standard recognizer and just state how many touches is required.

A good example can be found here: [Capture only UIView 2 finger UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301286/capture-only-uiview-2-finger-uipangesturerecognizer)